# Return HTTP CODE in custom validator Spring Rest

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-rest

I'm working on an API REST using Spring and I'm trying to create a new custom validator with 2 validations.

For each validator I want to return a different HTTP CODE to the users but I'm stuck on it, I just know that I can return a boolean in the isValid method.

I hope someone could help me or give me a better way to accomplish this thing.

#### UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("user")
public class UserController {
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<?> addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User 
     user, Errors errors)  {

    //Here I don't now How to read just one error from Validator class, I just want to return 1 error using the HTTP CODE
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT); //I'm just using a generic but I want to use the returned by Validator which has 2 validations and should return different errors
    }       
    return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
  }
 }
```

#### User.java

```
public class User {

    @NotNull
    private final String name;

    @NotNull
    @UserConstraint
    private final Integer age;

    public User(@JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("age") Integer age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

}
```

#### UserConstraint.java

```
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = UserValidator.class)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface UserConstraint {
   String message() default "Invalid age";
   Class<?>[] groups() default {};
   Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

#### UserValidator.java

```
public class UserValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UserConstraint, Integer>  {

        @Override
        public void initialize(UserConstraint constraintAnnotation) {
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isValid(Integer age, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

          if(age > 60) {
              //Here I want to return HTTP CODE 402 to the user 
              return false;
          } else if(age < 18) {
              //Here I want to return HTTP CODE 422 to the user 
              return false;
          }
          return true;  
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to do some validations with the age and I want to return a different HTTP CODE to users.

Comment: Why not use the standard Min/Max validators on age?

Comment: I need to return different HTTP CODES and message for each one, In addition I need to apply more cases to that method (with more logic).

Comment: i suggest that you can use **ThreadLocal** to set the valiation result in UserValidator, then you can get the value in UserController to check

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like that: at isValid method on UserValidator throw new own exception e.g UnderageUserException. Class UnderageException should extends RuntimeException and you need to annotate this with @ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY) for 422.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html <---- here you have a list of codes.
Then create controller annotated @AdviceController which will handle that exceptions from all controller classes.
edit:  https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring
here you have a nice guide to this

Answer (score 1):

You could throw a `ResponseStatusException`

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "error message");
```